# swiffy objects on ios and android play withoud sound

Tags: html, html5-audio, google-swiffy

I know that there is [no support](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/gettingstarted.html) for ios and android to play swiffy with sound

i looked everywhere on web to try to find a solution but i can't find. it's hard for me to believe that there is no solution for that.
does anyone has figure this out?

Comment: After a fruitless search, I can confirm that the answer is like you said - there is no support for ios and android to play swiffy with sound.

Answer (score 0):

Inside actionscript, you can send a getURL call to javascript where you have a hidden html5 mp3 player, something like:

```
getURL("Javascript:playSound();");
```

I'm still working in this but I hope this help you.